# Prevent Angular 2 from loading in Internet Explorer

Tags: angular

I want to prevent my Angular 2 app from loading when the web browser is any version of IE. I have tried to put a script tag in index.html that detects IE. This works fine, but when I am trying to redirect the app to a "not compatible page" via window.location.href, I am getting into a loop as my server is always serving index.html. Any best practices on this topic?

Comment: you may have multiple pages on server. Or you may have entire content of non compatible page in index.html and show\hide based upon Browser detection.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get away from using a script so this might not be the most helpful.  In the past I have used bowser to handle certain versions of IE.

https://github.com/ded/bowser